# jQuery Selector to select each Images & Sources inside the Dynamic Containers?

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I'm trying to detect all Images and its paths (Srcs) inside the `dynamic` containers. `dynamic` containers means the container patterns will be in array (dynamically).

Like:

```
var containers = new Array(
                            "div#menu",
                            "div#elem1",
                            "p.footernav"
                      );
```

The `containers` will be dynamically filled. Originally unknown before.
Then i will grab these areas in loop:

```
for (var i=0; i< containers.length; i++) {
    var html_source = $(containers[i]).html();
    ?
}
```

All i got is just these so far.
Then how do i detect the `IMAGES` and `SRC` of `<img src="..." />` inside each returned `var html_source`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var html_source = $(containers[i]).html();

// here you need to wrap html_source within
// $(), because html_source is string
// not jQuery object

$(html_source).find('img').map(function(index, el) {
  return el.src;
}).toArray();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GBZWs/5/)**

Comment: ha ha ++1 to you as well `Note: 45 sec` and you nailed the answer :P

Comment: Should i use another variable name instead of `i` under `map` method ? Coz `i` is not available since above. OR did you intentionally use `i` ?

Comment: @4lvin `i` within `map` mentioned `index`, will not effect your `i` at all.

Comment: @thecodeparadox I have done! :D :D would u mind pls upvote my useful question? :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12962/discussion-between-4lvin-and-thecodeparadox)